# How to handle Json Response of Async callable cloud function

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have the following function, trying to get the url Link created by Stripe API
It should return the following object

```
{
  "object": "login_link",
  "created": 1620954357,
  "url": "https://connect.stripe.com/express/VGAOul448UhS",
  "id": "lael_JTn3grKOB073gL"
}
```

Nodejs callable function (to be called in Dart / Flutter)

```
exports.loginLink = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const accountId = data.id;
  console.log('this is accountId ---->' + accountId);
  const loginLink = await stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(
  accountId
).then(() => {
  console.log(data.id)
  console.log(loginLink);
  return loginLink;
});

})
```

And called from Flutter as follow

```
  Future<void> getUrl() async {
    HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('loginLink');
    dynamic results = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
    'id': 'acct_1IpttSQgX5lyYgEb',});
    print (results.data);
    String urlLink = results.data;
  }
```

Firebase logs return Unhandled error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'loginLink' before initialization
at /workspace/index.js:41:15

Any help to get the url provided by stripe  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for your callable function instead:

```js
exports.loginLink = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const accountId = data.id;
  console.log('this is accountId ---->' + accountId);
  const loginLink = await stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(accountId);
  return loginLink;
})
```

Your original code was mixing `async/await` and `.then()` which isn't ideal.  Your original `return` statement only returned from the `then()` block, not the top-level function, so nothing actually got returned in the end.

Comment: yeah tried that before, the log returns loginLink: Unhandled error ReferenceError: loginLink is not defined
    at /workspace/index.js:37:3
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2021-05-17T21:51:48.947010099Z D loginLink: Function execution took 423 ms, finished with status code: 500

Comment: That's not an error I would expect; `loginLink` is defined... can you share the exact code that led to that error and note which line is line 37?

Comment: It s fine, was on my side, it works it returns loginLink as the object. I just need to understand how to retrieve it in my dart Flutter future function (I thought something like snap.data['url'])

Comment: If you `print(results)` what do you get?  Does that give you a hint as to where the `url` is?

Comment: it works just fine, I thought I needed to parse a Json object, but it returned a map, for other users, you handle the 'HttpsCallableResult'  object just using results.data['url']. Tks for the help